# Euler Characteristic $\mathbb{C} \backslash\{0,1\}$ and non-compact surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I am looking at various proofs of the Little and Big Picard Theorems. I am interested in the following question:

Without the Uniformization Theorem, can one calculate the Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0,1\}$? In general, how does one calculate the Euler characteristic of non-compact surfaces? Is there a formula?

I ask because, if one knew the Euler characteristic of $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0,1\}$, then one could apply the Uniformization Theorem to conclude that $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0,1\}$ has the unit disc as its universal cover. Lifting an entire function $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\backslash \{0,1\}$ to $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{C} \to U$ we obtain an "easy" proof of the Little Picard Theorem. Of course, this requires doing the work of proving the Uniformization Theorem.

Comment: I don't know much about complex analysis, so I don't know if what I'm going to say is useful to you, but your surface is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of two circles. You can easily compute its Euler characteristic then: $\chi = 1$. In general, a noncompact surface is homotopy equivalent to a graph (and computing the Euler characteristic of a graph isn't hard).

Comment: That sounds good.. However, I think that the Euler characteristic should be negative, given that the universal cover of $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0,1\}$ is the hyperbolic plane. Unless I'm missing something? Perhaps this thinking only holds for compact surfaces?

Comment: The Euler characteristic of the wedge of two circle should be $\chi=\color{red}-1$ since it counts $1$ vertex and $2$ edges, hence $\chi=1-2=-1$

Comment: Ah yes it's $\chi = -1$ of course, I mistakenly reverted the order.